# Was bedeutet "wäre gekommen" auf einer Zigarettenausgabe?

Tags: phrase, meaning-in-context

Once upon a time in Germany. On a cigarette machine in a super market (Rewe), I read the following text:

> wäre gekommen.

It clearly had umlaut dots. I stand there and read loudly “wäre gekommen” and another customer confirmed “ja, wäre gekommen”. It was not a poster, but a customer-direction text, written big and bold in a font that everybody could read from ca. five meters distance.

My understanding of it is:

> Wenn du bezahlt hättest, wäre es gekommen.

Could you please explain that information?

Comment: As a native speaker,  I wonder about the small w of "wäre". For me it implies that the beginning of the sentence is missing.

Comment: I bet it (originally) read "Ware kommt" (English: product is arriving). Is it possible that someone jokingly modified the text with a marker pen or the like?

Comment: Unklar, was die Frage ist. Vielleicht könnte ein Foto mehr verraten, aber so läd es nur zu wüsten Spekulationen ein.

Comment: I think Deve is up to something. But given that this happened "once upon a time", my bet is that a misunderstood "Ware kommt" eventually morphed into "wäre gekommen" in the OP's mind.